# How to get specific type control with openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How to get specific type control?I have tried like below,but always got null

```
function getAttControl(){
   var ctrls = map.getControls();

    for (var i = 0; i < ctrls.getLength(); i++) {
        if (ctrls.get(i) instanceof ol.control.Control) {
            return ctrls.get(i);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  var controls = map.getControls(); // this is a ol.Collection
  controls.forEach(function(control){
    console.info(control instanceof ol.control.Zoom);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible to do something like this:  return ctrls.forEach(function(control) {
   if (control instanceof $wnd.ol.control.Attribution) {
    return control;
   }